# Balls and bins lower bound with random algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, random-variables, balls-in-bins, algorithmic-randomness

Assume we have $n$ bins and $B \sim Binom(nk,p)$ balls to distribute in an equitable.

Furthermore, assume that each ball arrives one at a time and must be placed in a bin before the next arrives. Lastly, assume that we use a randomized algorithm that randomly places a ball in a bin at each iteration. In the simpler setting with a "greedy" algorithm we can say that each bin will receive $kp$ balls in expectation, but what lower bound can we argue on each bin in the randomized setting? Can we easily give a result such that for some $\gamma$ we have $$Pr\left(\frac{1}{n} B < \gamma\right)$$ is very small (say $< 1/n$)?

Comment: The setup may be more clear as we have $n$ bins and $Binom(nk,p)$ balls to distribute across the bins, which are arriving in an online stream (one at a time)

Comment: The event $\frac1nB < \gamma$ you're asking about seems to not care about which bins the $B$ balls land in at all; is this correct?

Comment: So my statement there is saying that each bin will receive $1/n$ balls so in order to give a high probability result on how many balls each bin will receive individually gives us that probability statement. I want to show each bin will have at least some amount of balls with high probability

Comment: If you are distributing the balls randomly, you are not guaranteed to get $\frac1n B$ balls in each bin.

Comment: I see. What is the more appropriate way of framing the probability question to show with high probability we can guarantee each bin receives $\geq X$ for some value $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that each bin gets at least $\gamma$ balls with high probability, it is **not** enough to show that $\Pr[\frac1n B > \gamma]$ is high. Some bins are going to get fewer than $\frac1n B$ balls.

If the total number of balls is $B \sim \text{Binomial}(nk,p)$, then the number of those balls that end up in the $i^{\text{th}}$ bin is $B_i \sim \text{Binomial}(nk, \frac{p}{n})$. Here is the reasoning: we can think of $B \sim \text{Binomial}(nk, p)$ as saying "we have $nk$ balls total, but each one of them has probability $p$ of actually being placed in a bin". In that case, each of the $nk$ balls has probability $\frac pn$ of being placed in the $i^{\text{th}}$ bin in particular.

We can bound the probability that $B_i$ is small by a [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error)). The expected number of balls in the $i^{\text{th}}$ bin is $nk \cdot \frac pn = pk$. Therefore $$\Pr[B_i \le (1-\delta) pk] \le e^{-\delta^2 pk/3}.$$
If we then want to bound the probability that *any* bin gets fewer than $(1-\delta)pk$ balls, then by the union bound it is at most $n e^{-\delta^2 pk/3}$.

If you want that probability to be $\frac1n$, then we want $e^{-\delta^2 pk/3} = \frac1{n^2}$, so $\delta^2 pk/3 = 2 \log n$ and $\delta = \sqrt{\frac{6 \log n}{pk}}$. So the threshold we can guarantee with this probability is $\gamma = (1 - \sqrt{\frac{6 \log n}{pk}})pk$, or $\gamma = pk - \sqrt{6pk \log n}$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I was completely missing the $B_i \sim Binom(nk, \frac{p}{n})$ aspect.